# NPM is not recognised while nodist is showing the version of node

Tags: node.js

I installed nodist and 2 versions of node when I run cmd prompt as admin I can see the version of node v4.4.5
However when I go to my project folder and run cmd prompt from that folder and run npm install I'm getting 'npm is not recognizes as an internal or external command'. I tried nodist from the same folder and I got 'nodist' is not recognised as internal or external command

Any idea whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you opening shell, try to run:

```
nodevars
```

Then you'll able to run npm and all globally installed modules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got nodevars is not recognised as an internal or external command as well.

Comment: Just find the path to node installation, nodevars must be there also. Than run: <full-path-to-node-dir>/nodevars